# What is a Scratch File?

Tags: javascript, file, directory, ide

I am currently trying to figure out all the functions that my IDE has, and I have come across a predefined folder when I create a project that is called 'scratches and consoles'.

The IDE only allows me to create Scratch Files but I don´t know what that kind of file is and what Is its purpose. Could someone give me a hand with this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's something like **temporary notes** with ability to highlight/format your code.

> Sometimes you may need to create temporary notes or draft up some code outside of the project context. Instead of switching to a different application for this purpose, you can use scratch files and scratch buffers.

You can read more about it at [JetBrains - Scratch files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scratches.html).

Comment: So basically are files in which I can put chunks of code to use at a later time, isn´t it?

Comment: Yes, it can be good for that too. Personally I am using it for notes which I've usually saved on my desktop via Notepad. Also when I am trying to write some SQL query just for testing purpose I write it in Scratch File because you can run them.